# How do I pass program-argument to main function in running spark-submit with a JAR?

Tags: java, apache-spark

I know this is a trivial question, but I could not find the answer on the internet.

I am trying to run a Java class with the `main` function with program arguments (`String[] args`).

However, when I submit the job using `spark-submit` and pass program arguments as I would do with

```
java -cp <some jar>.jar <Some class name> <arg1> <arg2>
```

it does not read the `arg`s.

The command I tried running was

```
bin/spark-submit analytics-package.jar --class full.package.name.ClassName 1234 someargument someArgument
```

and this gives

```
Error: No main class set in JAR; please specify one with --class
```

and when I tried:

```
bin/spark-submit --class full.package.name.ClassName 1234 someargument someArgument analytics-package.jar
```

I get

```
Warning: Local jar /mnt/disk1/spark/1 does not exist, skipping.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.relcy.analytics.query.QueryAnalytics
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Utils.scala:176)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:693)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:183)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:208)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

How can I pass these arguments? They change frequently on each run of the job, and they need to be passed as arguments.

Comment: You're supposed to pass the arguments after the jar. See the documentation on submitting Spark applications: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Arguments passed *before* the .jar file will be arguments to the JVM, where as arguments passed *after* the jar file will be passed on to the user's program.

```
bin/spark-submit --class classname -Xms256m -Xmx1g something.jar someargument
```

Here, `s` will equal `someargument`, whereas the `-Xms -Xmx` is passed into the JVM.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String s = args[0];
}
```

Comment: are you sure about that  ? I am using spark 1.6.2 on yarn and I get all the arguments include **--class classname ...** I get everything

Answer (score 10):

I found the correct command from [this tutorial](https://www.mapr.com/products/mapr-sandbox-hadoop/tutorials/spark-tutorial).

The command should be of the form:

```
bin/spark-submit --class full.package.name.ClassName analytics-package.jar someargument someArgument
```

Answer (score 1):

```
spark-submit --class SparkWordCount --master yarn --jars <jar1.jar>,<jar2.jar>
sparkwordcount-1.0.jar /user/user01/input/alice.txt /user/user01/output
```

Answer (score 0):

The first unrecognized argument is treated as the primaryResource (jar file in our case). Checkout [SparkSubmitArguments.handleUnknown](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/c41ef3981953a9d59030ea5f29386804b2d560a6/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/SparkSubmitArguments.scala#L450)

All the arguments after the primaryResource as treated as arguments to the application. Checkout [SparkSubmitArguments.handleExtraArgs](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/c41ef3981953a9d59030ea5f29386804b2d560a6/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/SparkSubmitArguments.scala#L472)

To better understand how the arguments are parsed, checkout [SparkSubmitOptionParser.parse](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/c41ef3981953a9d59030ea5f29386804b2d560a6/launcher/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/launcher/SparkSubmitOptionParser.java#L131). The above 2 methods are called from this method